# Unable to mount My Passport 1TB hardisk in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

When I attach my harddisk, it gives the following message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/gunnar/My Passport: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/gunnar/My Passport"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 3).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Anyone know what to do about this? It works just fine with my Windows PC.

And, - I am the COMPLETE amateur with Linux commands, so please be gentle with me , and keep it extremely simple. Thanks in advance.

Gunnar Sørensen, Oslo, Norway

Answer (score 14):

On your external harddrive, the master file table (MFT) and its copy (MFTMirr) are seemingly no longer consistent.

You might want to fix it using the Linux tool `ntfsfix` on the command line.

1. Hook the drive to your Linux machine.
2. Open a terminal by holding the <kbd>ALT</kbd> and the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> down while pressing the <kbd>t</kbd> key.
3. In the terminal, enter `which ntfsfix` and press <kbd>RETURN</kbd> to launch the command. If you receive a line like `/bin/ntfsfix`, this means that the tool is already installed and can be used to fix the problem. This should be the case.
4. Fixing a problem like the one you describe requires special rights a normal user doesn't have (for good reasons). Consequently, the repair operation has to be carried ot with **super user** priviledges. This is achieved by prefixing the command you want to use with `sudo`, which means **super user do**.
5. Since the external hard drive was **not mounted**, you need to call it by its device name. From the error message that you gave, we read that it is `/dev/sdb1`.
6. To sum it up: Enter `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1` in the terminal and press <kbd>RETURN</kbd>. You will be asked for your password. Enter that and press <kbd>RETURN</kbd> again.

Good luck!

Comment: This worked for me!